# Recording a gaming console onto my computer from my TV

Tags: video, digital-recording

So I have a TV with two types of inputs. Composite (just mono), and coaxial - yes it's a pretty old TV. I play a video game that I want to record some matches of onto my laptop so I can edit the clips and stuff.

My gaming system is hooked up to my TV via composite (just mono). What type of parts do I need to buy to be able to record from the TV onto my laptop from the gaming console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a [USB Video Capture Device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00392K4LQ) to connect the game to your laptop.

In order to also be able to view the game on the TV, you will need 2 [splitters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000M52X62) for the video and audio and an extra [composite cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V0DY7U).

You would run the yellow and white game console outputs to the splitters and attach the splitters directly to the Video Capture device.  The red cable goes into the Video Capture device directly.  Connect the yellow and white connectors of the extra cable between the splitters and the TV.

I'm not sure how much the video and sound quality will be affected by splitting the signal, so you may need to buy a better [splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003C2T03G) to get it to work without any loss.